# Flexbox Sticky Footer is Breaking my Navbar on Mobile

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, flexbox

When I add the following code to my CSS it breaks my navbar on mobile devices only:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#page-content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#footer-container {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

On desktop, my navbar functions perfectly when it expands. It pushes all the page content down as it should.

On mobile it is still expanding, but it doesn't push the page content down. It doesn't even keep its background color. It just expands the nav links down with no background.

I'm using bootstrap 4.4.1. It's a pretty generic navbar. I dropped the navbar code below.

As soon as I remove those 4 lines above from my CSS, my nav works perfectly on mobile. I just don't have a sticky footer anymore.

```
<nav class="mb-0 navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-555" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-555" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-555">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you provide a live demo on codepen.io or jsfiddle,net?

Comment: Not for a bit. I'm out of the house for a while unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a hacky way to make it work, though I hope for a real solution.

Basically, I just threw all the flexbox stuff in a media query like so:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #page-content {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    #footer-container {
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
}
```

So, it uses the flexbox while the navbar isn't collapsed, then when it collapses, stop using the flexbox stuff. This works for me perfectly because all of my pages have enough content that my footer is always at the bottom on mobile anyways.

Again, I think it's a hacky solution, but it works.